# no pasa valores a ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

favor su ayuda, con esta función quiero leer una BD por medio de 
    ajax, pero al parecer o esta pasando ningún parámetro. Cuando ingreso 
    informacion al input este hace algo, la pagina chispea y cuesta ingresar 
    letras, pero no muestra ninguna informacion

```
function chk_usuario(){

var pos_url = 'comprueba.asp';
var nombre = document.getElementById('solicitante').value;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (req) {
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (req.readyState == 4 && (req.status == 200 || req.status == 304)) {
document.getElementById('solicitante').innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
}
req.open('GET', pos_url +'?nombre='+nombre,true);
req.send(null);
}
}
<input type="text" name="solicitante"  id="solicitante" value="solicitante" 
class="form-control input-sm" onkeyup="chk_usuario();" />

<div id="solicitante"> </div>


comprueba.asp
response.expires=-1

nombre=request.querystring("nombre")


SQL1="select * from dotacion where ID = '"&nombre&"' "
Set Rs1 = Con2.Execute(SQL1)
if Rs1.eof = false then
   nombres = Rs1("nombres")
   Apellido_Pat = Rs1("a_paterno")
   Apellido_Mat = Rs1("a_materno")
   nom_sucursal = Rs1("GLOSA_OFICINA")
   Cargo = Rs1("CARGO")
 End if

response.write (nombres)

ademas, los valores quiero mostrarlos en otros inputs del formulario, nose 
si sera posible esto. de antemano gracias.
```

Comment: Ese no es AJAX.  Y además es vunerable a ataques de SQL Injección.

Comment: gracias Duston, es el código que he encontrado para realizar mas menos lo que busco. necesito autocompletar inputs, por eje con evento onkeyup y que vaya a buscar datos a la BD. con asp clasico.